# Is there any way to increase system volume in windows 10 with Command Line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, audio

I am working on a project and I want to increase system volume by using cmd (Command Line). I am running windows 10 is there any way to do this.
 I found `nircmd.exe` as a windows command for Windows XP and 7 but it does not show me on windows 10. It says

'SndVol32.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So it means it only works on Windows XP and 7.

So please give me any method to increase volume in my windows 10 system using Command Line (CMD).

I had tried also:
[image: My Command Line Output]

[image: My Windows Version]

Comment: I am able to increase the system volume in Windows 10 using nircmd.exe. Please [edit] your post and include the exact nircmd.exe command you're using to try to increase the system volume.

Comment: You've to download it from nirsoft.

Comment: Also, if this PC is connected to the internet (assuming so since you must download this program) Win 10 1511 has been out of support since Oct 10, 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer through comments thanks to Biswapriyo
 So you need to download the nircmd utility from the given link. Just scroll down to the end of the page and you will find the download link. After downloading just open the nircmd.exe and it will ask to add to the directory just press ok and it will work fine.
 the download link is here 
[Download NIRCMD.EXE](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an open-source software [adjust-volume.exe](https://github.com/WingTillDie/adjust-volume/releases/download/v2.0.0/adjust-volume.exe) to do the task

Usage:

```
# Set current sound volume to 0.2
./adjust-volume.exe .2

# Get current sound volume
./adjust-volume.exe
```

Repo:
https://github.com/WingTillDie/adjust-volume

Answer (score 0):

NirCmd System Requirements : This utility can work in all versions of Windows operating system: Windows 9x/ME, Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10.

I just tested this utility under Windows 10 and its working without any problem.

Commands that I used :

Increase the system volume by 2000 units (out of 65535)

```
nircmd.exe changesysvolume 2000
```

Decrease the system volume by 5000 units (out of 65535)

```
nircmd.exe changesysvolume -5000
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my PC see my question again.

Comment: It gives that error because you are writing nircmd command to a cmd which is at different directory. Before writing volume command you should navigate to directory which has nircmd.exe through cmd using CD command. For example "cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15"